# Viable Alternative to Adobe Flash?

Tags: flash

I'm using Flash for my website that hosts a number of rather complex ways of displaying calculations etc. It's not that it can't be done using say jQuery but I want it to remain relatively difficult to steal my code since it would leave the field wide open to competitors to set up sites like mine relatively easy.

However, now that many ppl surf the net with iPad and iPhone, I get requests to remove the Flash parts since these gadgets doesn't support flash.

So I ask you, is there today a viable option to flash that runs on basically all browsers, idependant on what hardware you are on (ipad, iphone etc)?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your calculations display interactive? Can't it be serverside generated content displayed as bitmap or vector?

Comment: Yes. And sometimes time critical i.e. containing them inside flash gives me "the best so far" option to make sure it isn't lagging too much because of an old browser that would render JavaScript slower etc. This can be a discussion in itself, I know, but we can leave it at saying it works very well today, giving most users the same conditions and possibilities.

Comment: Nice to know that the market is slowly moving developers away from flash. One has to thank Apple for that I guess.

Comment: Noufal, to me it seems rather odd to say, on a developer forum, that it is "nice to know" that a fellow developer has to remake his solution.

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking is actually in the heart of the Flash/HTML5 debate these days!

Few facts:

1/ With the preview release of Flash builder 4.5 last week, it becomes clear that Flash is moving towards the application side (mobile apps, desktop apps, ...).

2/ Iphone and Ipads don't support Flash in there browsers, but it's possible to develop Apps for it in Flash!

3/ You can now develop Android Apps with Flash!

I'm sure you will find lots of possible answers on the web, but here is my opinion:
Flash won't be available in the browser on every device, but you will be able to create applications with Flash for these devices!

So for your project, the only way to make sure that it will be available on every device, you kind of have to develop it with HTML/Jasvascript.
If you want to protect you code, you can always use a javascript obfuscator like this one: http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it myself but [Open Laszlo](http://www.openlaszlo.org/) can compile complex rich interfaces into either flash or into HTML+Javascript. The examples suggest that it's quite powerful. It might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Open Lazlo isn't an alternative. It's just a "layer" that then renders either JS or Flash. So basically, it's a Flash alternative that renders Flash. Not really a difference in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do the calculations server-side? That would make it really difficult to steal your code and the users won't have to install proprietary stuff.

Comment: In a word: no. The calculations are done visually, that's half the reasons why ppl use my site to begin with.

Comment: Can't you pass the visual user input to the server and ask it to give you a json/xml string that describes the necessary change in the image?

Answer (score 0):

No, not as far as I know. Especially with the added requirement that your code should be relatively obscured. Otherwise you could have gotten away using JS or SVG (the browser support regarding SVG isn't exactly great though).

Answer (score 0):

[GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) is a good choice.